# Certificate Auth. : the specified credentials were rejected by the server

Tags: ansible

It's been multiple days since I started trying enabling all my Windows hosts to be reachable with Ansible via the certificate authentication method. I use a script to configure WinRM and to create a self-signed certificate. On multiple hosts, it works fine and after the script is finished I can connect to them via certificate authentication but on some other (like 15-20% of them) it's impossible.

I get this error message:

```
fatal: [SERVERNAME]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "certificate: the specified credentials were rejected by the server",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

What is strange is that I don't see the login event in the Windows event viewer. Here is my WinRM configuration:

```
Service
    RootSDDL = O:NSG:BAD:P(A;;GA;;;BA)(A;;GR;;;IU)S:P(AU;FA;GA;;;WD)(AU;SA;GXGW;;;WD)
    MaxConcurrentOperations = 4294967295
    MaxConcurrentOperationsPerUser = 1500
    EnumerationTimeoutms = 240000
    MaxConnections = 300
    MaxPacketRetrievalTimeSeconds = 120
    AllowUnencrypted = false
    Auth
        Basic = true
        Kerberos = true
        Negotiate = true
        Certificate = true
        CredSSP = true
        CbtHardeningLevel = Relaxed
    DefaultPorts
        HTTP = 5985
        HTTPS = 5986
    IPv4Filter = *
    IPv6Filter = *
    EnableCompatibilityHttpListener = false
    EnableCompatibilityHttpsListener = false
    CertificateThumbprint
    AllowRemoteAccess = true
Winrs
    AllowRemoteShellAccess = true
    IdleTimeout = 7200000
    MaxConcurrentUsers = 10
    MaxShellRunTime = 2147483647
    MaxProcessesPerShell = 25
    MaxMemoryPerShellMB = 1024
    MaxShellsPerUser = 30
```

Both the listener and the certificate mapping are configured on the windows machine:

```
Listener
    Address = *
    Transport = HTTPS
    Port = 5986
    Hostname
    Enabled = true
    URLPrefix = wsman
    CertificateThumbprint = 927...C26E
    ListeningOn = 127.0.0.1, 172.20.x.x

CertMapping
    URI = *
    Subject = ansibleuser@localhost
    Issuer = 579f3eb1c3756339a246843f70e1a89b14fdc244
    UserName = ansibleuser
    Enabled = true
    Password
```

What I've tried up until now:

- Check the presence of the LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy registry key
- Configure the access to WinRM through winrm configSDDL default
- Check GPOs
- Change the password (check and uncheck password never expires,
  etc...)
- Create another local admin user
- Enable basic and unencrypted authentication
- Change the connection type to private (could not since the servers
  are domain joined)
- Run the script provided by ansible to configure WinRM

I don't understand what is going on and it's driving me nuts. Did someone encounter this problem before ?

I'm open to all suggestions, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

FINALLY found a solution to this problem:

Based on this thread [Client Certificate-based authentication stopped working for PS Remoting](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0209e182-c196-4e63-9974-a55e2b7d3bcb/client-certificatebased-authentication-stopped-working-for-ps-remoting?forum=winserversecurity), I found out that a registry key named "ClientAuthTrustMode" should be set to the value "2" and, with that, the error message magically disappears.

Here is a Microsoft article detailing the implication of the key : [Overview of TLS - SSL (Schannel SSP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/tls/what-s-new-in-tls-ssl-schannel-ssp-overview)

Here is a simple powershell command to flip the switch :

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL -Name ClientAuthTrustMode -Type DWord -Value 2
```

Hopefully that will help someone out there.

Comment: In my case the session was working on some systems and not others, with the same cert and a mix of operating system versions. The 'access denied' error message was absolutely useless and I was in the dark. Nothing made sense until I read this answer and, after two full days of hell, this saved the day. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Your solution! It solves my problem also.

We had lot of servers using ansible and WINRM with certificate based authentication, but only one of our servers had the same issue as yours was...

The only one interesting difference, what I've found on your shared settings is this:
ListeningOn = 127.0.0.1, 172.20.x.x
This is also same as mine... localhost is in the first place...
ListeningOn = **127.0.0.1**, 19x.1xx.19.98, ::1

Other servers in our setup is add the network interface on the first place like this:
ListeningOn = 19x.16.61.38, **127.0.0.1**, ::1

I really don't know, it matters or not, but this is the only difference, what I've found.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error but for a different reason.  We noticed that the auth failures were happening on machines that also had restricted Internet access. Turns out that if the server can't reach the CRL for the signing certificate, it will refuse to authenticate the client cert.  Look for the `X509v3 CRL Distribution Points` property on the client cert (pipe the cert through `openssl x509 -noout -text` to see these properties) and ensure that the server can reach that URL.