# Certificate: the specified credentials were rejected by the server

Tags: linux, ansible, winrm

Need help Securing WinRM for Ansible with Certificates. Ive followed a couple tutorial on setting it up but Im getting an error when testing with `ansible web -m win_ping -vvv`.

I get the error:

```
[server ip address] | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "certificate: the specified credentials were rejected by the server",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

when i run the command `nc -vz [ip-address] 5986` it says the connection succeeded. So the port is reachable.

```
winrm e winrm/config/Listener

Listener
    Address = *
    Transport = HTTP
    Port = 5985
    Hostname
    Enabled = true
    URLPrefix = wsman
    CertificateThumbprint
    ListeningOn = 127.0.0.1, 128.149.127.170, ::1, fe80::f94:6d4a:dffe:aa66%12

Listener
    Address = *
    Transport = HTTPS
    Port = 5986
    Hostname = [hostname]
    Enabled = true
    URLPrefix = wsman
    CertificateThumbprint = E80477462AD9398D6859FE9070693334BCEFBBD6
    ListeningOn = 127.0.0.1, 128.149.127.170, ::1, fe80::f94:6d4a:dffe:aa66%12



winrm get winrm/config/client/auth
Auth
    Basic = false [Source="GPO"]
    Digest = false [Source="GPO"]
    Kerberos = false
    Negotiate = true
    Certificate = true
    CredSSP = false

PS C:\> winrm get winrm/config/service/auth
Auth
    Basic = false [Source="GPO"]
    Kerberos = true
    Negotiate = true
    Certificate = true
    CredSSP = true
    CbtHardeningLevel = Relaxed
```

host file

```
[web]
[server ip address]

[web:vars]
ansible_user=[user]
ansible_password=[password]
ansible_connection=winrm
ansible_winrm_transport=certificate
ansible_winrm_cert_pem=/home/user/.ssh/client_cert.pem
ansible_winrm_cert_key_pem=/home/user/.ssh/client_key.pem
ansible_port=5986
ansible_winrm_scheme=https
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore
```

I confirmed that my user is local user and admin on the windows server.

Comment: running with -vvvvv might help

Comment: It looks like you are doing client certificate-based authentication which is failing because the Remote System, Windows did reject the content of `/home/user/.ssh/client_cert.pem`. Maybe [Certificate Auth.: the specified credentials were rejected by the server #311](https://github.com/diyan/pywinrm/issues/311) or [Certificate Auth.: the specified credentials were rejected by the server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67422353/6771046) answer your question.

Comment: @U880D Ive tried both those commands and had no luck. I just end up getting a different error message.: "certificate: An attempt has been made to operate on an impersonation token by a thread that is not currently impersonating a client.  (extended fault data: {'transport_message': 'Bad HTTP response returned from server. Code 500', 'http_status_code': 500, 'wsmanfault_code': '1309', 'fault_code': 's:Receiver', 'fault_subcode': 'w:InternalError'})"